# What does +<>c.<> mean in C# memory snapshot?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

In the "Paths to Root" of memory snapshot an entry reads:

```
DashboardVM+<>c  
   DashboardVM+<>c [Static variable DashboardVM+<>c.<>9]
```

What does the cryptic line `+<>c.<>9` mean exactly? My guess would be ctor line 9, but it does not appear to be the case. 
I am interested in understanding the information provided by snapshot rather than resolving this particular case.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks, I would have never been able to find *that* question with keywords from this one.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that my list is quite out-of-date. Consult the Roslyn sources for the up-to-date rules for generating magic names. I think this is the place to look: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/f8c6405b05f56a8083d5d007cdd3aa2c0d500a51/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/Synthesized/GeneratedNames.cs